# In R, mapping column classes to a character vector without a for loop

Tags: r, class, mapping

Say I have a dataframe with X columns, and a character vector of length X containing classes such as the following:

```
classes <- c("character","numeric","numeric","character","character")
```

How would I "map" those classes to my dataframe's columns without the use of a for loop?

Comment: Can you give an example of how would your data frame and map should be?

Comment: By "map" I meant not an object but a process by which the df's column classes would be "matched" to the classes defined in the character vector (see Roland's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called `Map`. ;)

```
DF <- iris
classes <- c("character","numeric","numeric","character","character")
DF[] <- Map(as, DF, classes)
sapply(DF, class)
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
# "character"    "numeric"    "numeric"  "character"  "character"
```

Of course, this is still a loop and won't be more efficient than a `for` loop. It's clearer syntax, though.

Comment: Map! How well thought (darn case sensitivity). Thanks for the workable example. :)

Comment: `Map` is basically our trusty friend `mapply` with different defaults.

Comment: Indeed, `mapply(FUN = as, iris, classes, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` also does the trick. And wrapping this -- or the `Map(...)` -- inside a call to `as.data.frame` completes the job.

Comment: You don't need `as.data.frame` if you assign to a data.frame.

Comment: `class(DF)` gives `"list"`, not `"data.frame"`

Comment: @DominicComtois So? A data.frame is also a list and `[<-.data.frame` works just fine if you pass it a list.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, I mean the 2nd part of your last comment

Comment: I see now that I forgot something in my example. See the edit.